# How to affect configuration of IIS properties using Web Setup Project in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, setup-deployment, web-setup-project

I just built a setup.msi file using the Web Setup Project template within Visual Studio 2005 to deploy my web application to another web server.

While it works OK, it results in a new virtual directory on the target webserver that requires a fair bit of custom (i.e. manual) configuration steps using INETMGR on the target webserver.

I've noticed the Web Setup Project provides for various "editors" such as "Registry Editor", "User Interface Editor", etc. but I could not find anything that enables me to automate configuration tasks such as:

```
- How to change "Execute permissions" from "Scripts only" to "Scripts and Executables"

- How to disable "Anonymous access" and check "Integrated Windows authentication" 

- How to set a particularfile.aspx as the default content page (instead of default.aspx)
```

Are customizations like this possible with this project template or should I include something like a "ReadMe.txt" in the deployment? Thanks.

EDIT: 09/09/09

```
- How to add a Path such that installing user can put the code somewhere other than c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ 

That is, when the .msi runs, the only choice for "Site" is "Default Web Site" and it cannot be changed at install time. 

NOTE: My development PC (where my Web Setup Project is) runs Windows XP and thus IIS 5.1; I do not see any properties exposed for the Web Application Folder that look appropriate; only something called Property with a value called TARGETDIR.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to change "Execute permissions" from "Scripts only" to "Scripts and
>   Executables"

1. right-click on setup project
2. select view > file system
3. select web application folder
4. edit properties "ExecutePermission"

> How to disable "Anonymous access" and check "Integrated Windows
>   authentication"

I'm looking for the same thing myself, but i think it needs a custom action. Check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/SetIISettings.aspx

> How to set a particularfile.aspx as the default content page (instead of
>   default.aspx)

1. right-click on setup project
2. select view > file system
3. select web application folder
4. edit properties "DefaultDocument"

Comment: @ala - thanks for the detail on the 2 examples above. The article at codeproject.com was helpful (opens up a whole new thing I had no idea existed!). I also want to allow the installer to specify a physical path to allow installed website to be somewhere other than c:\inetpub\wwwroot\SameNameAsVirtualDirectory.